Which language is preferable for Durga shapta shati?
Chandi path or the Durga shaptashati is available in many languages like Hindi , Bengali etc. can anyone tell which language is preferred to get the maximum benefits? Also can the Durga shapta shati be chanted mentally or do we have to chant it loudly?
